# Guardar Lista L1 en Lista L2 y modificar L2 sin afectar a L1

Tags: c#, lista, variables, datos, modificaciones

Tengo una clase Personaje, la cual tiene muchas variables, entre las cuales algunas listas de string, int, y clases propias.
En mi programa, uso una variable Personaje_base para ir rellenándole datos.

```
P_base.Nombre = "Pepito";
P_base.Apellido = "palotes";
p_base.Idiomas = new List<idioma> { idioma1, idioma2, idioma3 };
...
```

Vale pues, tengo un sistema para predecir que opciones desbloqueará a futuro una elección ahora. Para ello cuando paso por encima (mousehover) de una opción la relleno en un Personaje_auxiliar y comparo este con el Personaje_base para ver las diferencias.
Para ello, necesito mantener actualizado periodicamente a Personaje_auxiliar con los datos actuales de Personaje_base.

`P_aux = p_base;`

y acto seguido le añado la información futurible a Personaje_auxiliar.

El problema viene ahora, pues cuando añado información a las listas de Personaje_auxiliar, se añade automáticamente a las listas de Personaje_base.
Probé creando un método en la clase Personaje, por si el código anterior estuviese provocando el problema.

`P_aux.Adoptar_Personaje(P_base);`

```cs
Public class Personaje
{
...
    Public void Adoptar_Personaje(Personaje p)
    {
        nombre = p.Nombre;
        apellido = p.Apellido;
        idiomas = p.Idiomas;
        ...
    }
...
}
```

y así... pero con mismos resultados. Si modifico listas en Personaje_auxiliar también se modifican en Personaje_base.
Alguna idea sobre porque pasa esto? Como puedo evitarlo? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno he podido arreglarlo así:

`P_aux.Idiomas = new List<Idioma>(P_base.Idiomas);`